# is java.lang.reflect.Method invoke thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I use org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(object) to get PropertyDescriptor[] and use them readMethod to get value.

**getPropertyDescriptors** will get Methods from **cache**.

So only one method instance call the invoke() for specific Class and field in multi threads.

**Is ok call one method.invoke() in multi threads if the object' method is thread safe ?**

```
        PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(object);
        propertyDescriptors[0].getReadMethod().invoke(object)
```

if userInfo' s every function is thread safe, () -> methods[0].invoke(userInfo)) run in multi thread is ok ?

```
    Method[] methods = UserInfo.class.getMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        new Thread(
            () -> methods[0].invoke(userInfo))
            .start();
    }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? The method itself does not modify anything so there is nothing that could go wrong if multiple threads are involved. Or are you worried about PropertyDescriptor and related methods? If so that is a separate question.

Comment: @Clashsoft I am sure that PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(object)  is thread safe. Method.invoke will lazy init methodAccessor . but it should be thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a method only uses stack variables, then it is threadsafe. Stack variables are scoped.

Looking at the source code for [PropertyUtilsBean](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.html), I only see stack variables.

Therefore, `PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors` is threadsafe.

... but your question was about `java.lang.reflect.Method`. [Looking at that code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b170c8376d683a18acf786ac69a462da0dbf1386/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Method.java#L493-L568), I see it relies on `java.lang.reflect.Method`.

The `Method` class has no static members, only instance members which live on the stack. All of its methods are similar. `Method` subclasses [`Executable`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b170c8376d683a18acf786ac69a462da0dbf1386/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Executable.java) which also has no static members. `Executable` implements [`AccessibleObject`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b170c8376d683a18acf786ac69a462da0dbf1386/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.java#L80-L93) which also has two static sections of code, which are only invoked when the JVM starts up:

```java
    static {
        // AccessibleObject is initialized early in initPhase1
        SharedSecrets.setJavaLangReflectAccess(new ReflectAccess());
    }

    static void checkPermission() {
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (sm != null) {
            // SecurityConstants.ACCESS_PERMISSION is used to check
            // whether a client has sufficient privilege to defeat Java
            // language access control checks.
            sm.checkPermission(SecurityConstants.ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
```

`AccessibleObject` extends `AnnotatedElement`, which has no static members.

In conclusion, I believe `java.lang.reflect.Method` is threadsafe.

Comment: methodAccessor is as field of Method. but for one class and one method , every method instance use the same methodAccessor instance . I thought Mehod.invoke is thread safe too .

Comment: Within a given class, non-static members can all reference the same object and still be typesafe. They are isolated from each other because they are separate instances.

Comment: Call PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors in different time for same class , same method instance will be returned from cache. same method instance will be call invoke() in multi thread .

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say

Comment: I edit the question.  I mean () -> methods[0].invoke(userInfo)) run in multi thread is ok , thanks ?

Comment: As I said in my answer: Yes :)

Answer (score 0):

> is java.lang.reflect.Method invoke thread safe

Mike implied this but the short answer is that calling a `method.invoke(...)` is thread safe if and only if the method itself is thread safe.  This means that if cannot change any fields in the object nor can it refer to any non-final fields from the object.

There is really nothing special about the `method.invoke(...)` reflection.  A call to the method directly from multiple threads comes under the same scrutiny from a thread-safe standpoint.